# Review ban due strange conditions

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, review-suspension

At first I knew before clicking on edit that this question was deleted and I wanted to check how the review page will react on it. A ban was not exactly what I was expecting.

Here check yourself this review:
https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/7996248

The answer is quiet long and contains many information. IMHO that answer is helpful, just the image is wrongly embedded. Just guessing that this answer was been deleted together with the answering user caused by heavy advertising for a library. Let's call this one native advertising which looks fine for me in this case.

What do you guys think about it? I think that my review was not wrong.

Comment: Sure looks like a version of spam to me, which is how it was flagged and deleted.

Comment: You should make sure to close delete questions like these when you see them as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regardless of possible spam, that question was a recommendation question and is off-topic on Stack Overflow (because it attracts spam in the first place). It should not be answered, yet you chose to edit one of its answers into shape.

Unfortunately, in this specific context that is not the right thing to do, which means you indeed have failed the review.

That said, a review ban is not triggered by a single failed review, so you probably have failed other ones along the way. There is no other solution than letting the ban expire, then being more careful when reviewing, I'm afraid.

Comment: My review was about the answer not the question. That is true that this was not my first wrong review, however there where some similar cases where I thought for me, well you can see it in that way but I do not. In a second case I was wrong, that happens^^ Back to topic: why would be an edit wrong? It would had improved the answer anyway.

Comment: "well you can see it in that way but I do not" There are some stupid audits, but it sure looks like they mostly work just fine based on your comment.

Comment: @rekire, review audits are all about doing the right thing in the right situation. There are lots of situations when an edit would be appropriate, but when it's not the case we expect you to use your other privileges (downvoting, closing, deleting, etc.). And yes, reviewing an answer in isolation is not ideal, that's why the question itself is available in the same page.

Comment: @PeeHaa I never counted them, but I guess I passed more then 90% (just because they are not so often, and some fails break the statistics)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi general speaking: if there is great answer on a crappy question I should vote for deletion? Your last comment let me think that.

Comment: @rekire He didn't say that.  And this also isn't a great answer.  It's spam, posted to a crap question.  All of it should be deleted.

Comment: @rekire, it's not that simple. If the answer is *really* great and the question *not too* crappy, bringing out the big guns is not necessary. Note that in our specific case, the question is really crappy and the answer not great at all.

Comment: @Servy I was generally speaking not about the reviewed answer, but I agree that it should be deleted both.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi you are right, I agree with you now too.

Comment: If the *question* shouldn't be there, why is an *answer* forming part of an audit?