# Improve audit text

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, review-audits

As we all know, the audit system is not infallible. It may be improved in the future, but will always have some problem cases. The current text is at best condescending. Worse, it incorporates an obviously false assumption that the reviewer's action, if not expected by the audit system, must be wrong, and due to a failure to pay attention.

In the cases in which I have failed an audit, my problem was often paying more attention than the audit system allowed for, such as finding a duplicate and being told I was wrong to vote to close the question because it was well-written.

I suggest changing the text to be more direct, factual, and realistic.

If the reviewer's action matches the expected action:

> This is an audit. Your action
>   matched the expected action. Thank you for your participation in the
>   review system.

If the reviewer's action does not match the expected action:

> This is an audit. Your action was not consistent with the audit
>   system's expected action, XXXX. Please carefully re-examine your decision.
>   Frequent audit mismatches indicate a problem, and may result in a
>   review ban.

(Replace "XXXX" with the action or actions the audit system would have accepted.)

The text on the button should be changed from "I understand" to something that is appropriate even when the reviewer is right and the audit system wrong, such as "Done" or "Continue".

Comment: This sounds really... Passive.

Comment: @Shog9 until the new audit selection process is put into play, I think passive might be good. Right now getting yelled at by a banner, when I know that it is wrong, can cause some... emotions.

Comment: I feel the same way about [compiler errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31234003/maybe-my-understanding-of-class-access-7-isnt-correct-but), but have learned with time that although it's not impossible for them to be triggered by bugs in the compiler, I should at least check my code first. Incidentally, that question is the most-failed close audit for the past week.

Comment: Understand suggestion brought this to mind: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188780/review-audits-and-i-understand-button/ I still think [Brad's idea](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188780/review-audits-and-i-understand-button/188790#188790) is the best way to handle these.

Comment: @Shog9 that could possibly even be something to pass off from mods/devs to high rep users to deal with obvious invalid claims maybe? Especially if the reviewing users left reasons for them being invalid, whether they be canned replies or custom description. Or would that be better kept at the mod level?

Comment: @Shog9 I upvoted Brad's idea soon after it was posted, and I still want to see it implemented. However, it was posted two years ago, with no signs of action. This proposal is deliberately minimalist, in the hope that it will get by whatever has prevented implementation of bigger changes, including Brad's suggestion.

Comment: Typical compiler error messages have similar style to that I am proposing for audit messages - a simple statement of what the compiler thinks is going on. I don't think I have ever had a compiler order me to "Stop! Look and listen." or tell me I have failed.

Answer (score 11):

I recognize I will pose a view on this that probably not many people will like.

I'll say one thing for the current text: at least it really lands home - and when it does land home for a good reason, because someone is robo reviewing, being disruptive, *is drunk* or not paying attention for other reasons, I am really glad it is written in a way designed to be a wake up call in the form of a slap in the face. Just like the audit system is a necessary evil, so too do I see the anger-inducing audit fail text as a necessary evil. Let me explain why.

Say that the text is changed to something as neutral and *indirect* as this, where is that slap in the face then when it is sorely needed? Its gone!

Now a bit of musing: is it really bad that the audit failure text makes or tries its best to make you feel emotional, siding towards anger, by default? I don't think so myself. Either it makes you angry because you got caught (sucks to be you), or it makes you angry because you think about it and you realize it is incorrect, which might just push you to act on it and get a situation fixed - such as an unfair audit question being blocked from actually being an audit question. Whereas otherwise you would just shrug it off and take the review vacation.

Putting that in the context of meta: there are many meta questions about (failed) audits. Many of them of the "suck it up" variety and are just noise, but there are also a fair few that really make a difference. What fueled those meta questions to be created? I want to believe a certain condescending audit failure message has a big part to play in it.

In short: I see more loss than gain here.

Comment: This ignores the fact that the only currency SO has to attract people to do the bulk of the work is offering fun games. Largely because of the anger-inducing messages, reviewing is not a fun game for me, so why should I play it?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Do you really want to claim that a piece of generic text that everyone gets is the entire reason that you would not find reviewing fun anymore? Of course not, there would have to be far more compelling reasons.  .

Comment: In your answer, you compared the text to "a slap in the face". I don't like, and will not tolerate, having my face slapped even metaphorically.

Comment: For a lot of users in a lot of queues, there's **nothing** they can do about a bad audit. For example, your typical 4500-rep reviewer in Late Answers who gets slapped with one of those boneheaded "durr, there's a link in this answer, it must be link-only!" deletion audits has exactly zero recourse: they can't vote to undelete, they can't counter-flag, they can't even see the deleted answer! Getting angry because some other users did stupid stuff that you can't undo *at all* is unproductive.

Comment: I'm going to suggest somewhere between the question and this response.  Maybe not as passive, but not quite as aggressive as the current situation either.  Mentally, when I see the "I Understand" button, I think "I understand that the audit system needs improved, yes".

Comment: @Gimby that piece of generic text has stopped me doing reviews. Simple. There are many high-rep users who agree, and the site has lost their input as well. (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298506/383414)

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier (and patricia too) That's really a shame and I really mean that. But luckily there are others who pickup the torch. I knew that there were going to be highly resistant comments to this particular nasty opinion of mine; I'm actually shocked it has upvotes. But there you have it - the above is said knowing full well all that has been discussed about this subject. I feel no shame in posting this answer as a result of it, if only to do the right thing and actually answer in meta questions rather than only sticking to the comments.

Comment: @Gimby meta is a great place to have discussions like this where the unicorn coins matter even less. Posting non-populist answers is something I support wholeheartedly, and to be honest I too am often surprised to get upvotes on some of my posts.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan (and Richard), why don’t you post your view as an answer here? Like Gimby, I’m a bit surprised that this one has that much publicity (although I *also* upvoted it, because I *have* been caught by the audit system while not paying attention, and that slap was deserved). Maybe it’s time for a second view.

Comment: @JonasWielicki I have already stated my recommendation as the original feature-request.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan True, I should probably get sleep instead of surfing meta.